# jQuery problems with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to do here is if the selection is equal to value 10 the click function to be available only if selection is equal to 10. But when i change to other ex. category with different value the radio click function is still available. ?

I have 6 radio boxes with value 1,2,3,4,5,6 so what i want to do if value == 4 to slidedown another div while i'm in category with value 10.(selection).

How can i fix this problem  ? Here is my sample code.

```
$('#category').on('change', function () {

    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('#slidedown'+selection).slideDown(200);

    if(selection == '10'){
        $("input:radio[name='checkbox']").click(function() {
            var radio = $(this).val();
            if(radio == '4' && selection == '10') {
                $('#slidedown'+selection).slideUp();    
            } else {
                $('#slidedown'+selection).slideDown();  
            }                    
        });
    });
```

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

EDIT : I want to slideUp the currect div which is slided down by the category value if radio box with value 4 is checked.

Comment: Please show your HTML markup, what is the element with id `category`?

Comment: <select name="category" id="category"> The select input with my categories options

Answer (score 1):

You should have another `selection` var inside the `click` callback:

```
$('#category').on('change', function () {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('#slidedown'+selection).slideDown(200);            
});    

    $("input:radio[name='checkbox']").click(function() {
        var selection = $('#category').val();   //This does the trick
        var radio = $(this).val();
        if(radio == '4' && selection == '10') {
            $('#slidedown_another').slideUp();    
        } else {
            $('#slidedown_another').slideDown();  
        }                    
    });
```

Also, callbacks must be separated for not binding a new listener each time

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This could work. But as you can see i'm making another if(selection == '10') where i'm slidingDown another different div tags. Thats becuase here i have another if selection == 10. I'm not sliding only the default div which have to be slided down but if selection is 10 the default div and another div to be slided down based on the category requirements.

Comment: But it's included in your `if(radio == '4' && selection == '10')` condition, right?

Comment: Yeah. Its included like this: if(selection == '10'){ 
        $("input:radio[name='checkbox']").click(function() {
            var selection = $('#category').val();
             var radio = $(this).val();
     if(radio == '4' && selection == '10') {
            $('#slidedown_another').slideUp();    
    } else {
     $('#slidedown_another').slideDown();  
    }    
         
   });

Comment: And based on selection 10 i want to activate the radio function and after the radio function i'm sliding down another div. I dont have idea how can i fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the `disabled` property to enable and disable the radio buttons.

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('#slidedown'+selection).slideDown(200);

    $('input:radio[name=checkbox]').prop('disabled', selection != '10');
});

$("input:radio[name='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var radio = $(this).val();
    if(radio == '4') {
        $('#slidedown_another').slideUp();    
    } else {
        $('#slidedown_another').slideDown();  
    }                    
});
```

Your code is adding a handler when the select has the correct value, but it never *removes* the handler when the select changes to a different value. Also, every time they select `10` it was adding *another* handler, so the handler would then run multiple times.

Comment: Ahh, got a little confused because he named his radio buttons _checkbox_.

Comment: Make a fiddle if you want me to troubleshoot more.